# mod_wsgi not found for apache/windows

Tags: windows, django, apache, mod-wsgi

My apache can't locate mod_wsgi on windows. I'm using apache 2.2 and the server starts correctly with the default httpd.conf.

I placed mod_wsgi.so into apache's modules directory (C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\modules) with read/execute permission for all users. I added the following line to the default httpd.conf

> LoadModule wsgi_module
>   modules/mod_wsgi.so

And i get this error when trying to start apache. Anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 129 of
>   C:/Program Files/Apache Software
>   Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf:
>   Cannot load C:/Program Files/Apache
>   Software
>   Foundation/Apache2.2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
>   into server: The specified module
>   could not be found.
>
> [Tue Nov 23 17:41:55 2010] [warn] (OS
>   995)The I/O operation has been aborted
>   because of either a thread exit or an
>   application request.  : winnt_accept:
>   Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.
>
> [Tue Nov 23 17:41:56 2010] [notice]
>   Child 7384: Released the start mutex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is the exact name of the mod_wsgi module file that you stuck in modules directory. Did you rename it from what was downloaded? Did you ensure you didn't stick an extra .so in the name so as to get mod_wsgi.so.so? Windows may be hiding one of the extensions if you did do that.

Comment: The filename is correct (mod_wsgi.so), what else could be wrong?

Comment: Permissions on the file, such that user that Apache service runs as can't read it.

Comment: I duplicated the permissions from the other modules (which loads correctly) to mod_wsgi, but it's still showing the same error.

Comment: Was Python installed for all users and not just yourself?

Comment: I used the non-interactive installer which defaults to current user unless you set ALLUSERS=1

Comment: Just one more item to add to @Graham's answer:  Be careful of architecture mismatches.  I had a 32 bit apache and 64 bit python running on this rig and it caused me problems.

Comment: @kefeizhou I face same problem with you, my question is where should i put ALLUSERS=1?

Comment: Had the same problem: Python was not installed for all users.
@GrahamDumpleton: Can you add this to your answer above? Some people (including me) do not look into the comments at the first time.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is that Apache 2.2 is installed as 32-bit while Python was installed as 64-bit on a 64-bit machine.  I had a situation where anything python mod_wsgi and legacy mod_python apps were erroring. If you are running 32-bit Apache it only likes to find 32-bit Python no matter the version.

Answer (score 0):

See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10553087/849417) for a simple solution. Your apache is most likely a 32bit installed on a 64-bit windows, or otherwise. Or you have a filename mistake. To verify the filename is correct and exists with the extension mentioned: Click the "Tools" menu in any explorer window, Click "Folder Options" then in the "View" tab, uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types" and click [Apply] or [OK]. Then you can proceed after your verification of `mod_wsgi.so`

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
LoadFile "c:/yourPythonPath/python**.dll"
```

** => version of your python

on apache.config

Answer (score 0):

Envirnoment python3.8.0 Apache2.4.41 mod_wsgi4.7.1
I have install the mod_wsgi in my global python envirnoment, The are some information from output to the command line(my python home is E:\Program Files\python3.8):

Extracting mod_wsgi-4.7.1-py3.8-win-amd64.egg to e:\program files\python3.8\lib\site-packages
Adding mod-wsgi 4.7.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing mod_wsgi-express-script.py script to E:\Program Files\Python3.8\Scripts
Installing mod_wsgi-express.exe script to E:\Program Files\Python3.8\Scripts

so there is a executable file mod_wsgi-express.exe in the directory E:\Program Files\Python3.8\Scripts and you can run the following command in your command line

mod_wsgi-express module-config

my output is:

LoadFile "E:/Program Files/Python3.8/python3.8.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "E:/Program Files/Python3.8/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi-4.7.1-py3.8-win-amd64.egg/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp38-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "E:/Program Files/Python3.8"

copy the output to you httpd.conf
out produre is reference from https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst
this is my first time answer question and my monther language isn't English, I hope I can help you.